# Deriving probability of exactly one event occuring

Tags: probability, statistics, axioms

> Show that for any events A and B, the probability that exactly one of them occur is
>   Pr(A) + Pr(B) − 2 Pr(A ∩ B).

Solution: The probability that exactly one event occurs is
$$ Pr ((A \cap B^c) \cup (A^c ∩ B)) = Pr(A ∩ B^c) + Pr(A^c ∩ B) \\ = (Pr(A) − Pr(A ∩ B)) + (Pr(B)− Pr(A ∩ B))\\ = Pr(A) + Pr(B) − 2 Pr(A ∩ B).$$

---

I am going through this question and I don't understand how $$P(A \cap B^c) = (Pr(A) − Pr(A ∩ B))$$ and $$P(A^c \cap B) = (Pr(B) − Pr(A ∩ B))$$

If someone could explain this to me, I would be very happy.

Note: I understand why this works with a venn diagram, but I can't derive its formula...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even without measure theory:

If $A$ has occurred, the also, either $B$ has occurred or or $B$ has not occurred. 
The probablility that $A$ has occurred and $B$ has not occurred is by definition 
$P(A\cap B^c)$ and similarly  the probablility that $A$ has occurred and $B$ has
is $P(A\cap B)$.

So 
$$
P(A) = P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c) \\
P(A\cap B^c) = P(A) - P(A\cap B)
$$

Comment: You are so awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with measure theory?  If so, $P$ is a measure, and $P(A) = P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap B^{c})$ (since measures are countably additive as long as the sets are pairwise disjoint), which implies $P(A) - P(A \cap B) = P(A \cap B^{c})$.

You can apply a similar argument for $P(A^{c} \cap B)$.

Comment: This answer is entirely correct, but at the same time, I can't believe that anyone familiar with measure theory would be asking this question.

Comment: @potato I'm not going to take criticism from a spud... Just kidding.  Maybe someone out there will find this answer useful (maybe someone familiar with measure theory but not with the fact that the probability function is a measure).

Comment: Potato is right, I have never done any measure theory before. I'm just starting with probability now. Also, nice pun, user46944.

Answer (score 1):

You could think of it like $$P(B) \cup P(B^{c})=1$$ so $$P(A)=P(A)\cap(P(B) \cup P(B^{c}))$$ and therefore $$P(A \cap B^c) = (P(A) − P(A ∩ B))$$

I don't know if that is formally written correctly, but maybe conveys the right logic.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the identity

$P(A^c∩B)=(P(B)−P(A∩B))$

is that the two sets $A^c∩B$ and $A∩B$ are disjoint and make up $B$, that is

$(A^c∩B) \cup (A∩B) = B.$

The probability of the left hand side is thus equal to the probability on the right hand side, and since the union on the left hand side is disjoint, it is equal to the sum of the probabilities of each of the sets in the union.